# S3: Is there a way to convert objects.all into a Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

So here is my code, basically it prints the content of an S3 bucket.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_name = 'test-bucket-2'

bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
def print_object_list():
    for object in bucket.objects.all():
        print(object)
```

When I run `print_object_list()` i get:

```
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='test-bucket-2', key=u'Guest.txt')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='test-bucket-2', key=u'infolder1/')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='test-bucket-2', key=u'infolder1/Guest.txt')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='test-bucket-2', key=u'infolder2/')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='test-bucket-2', key=u'infolder3/')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='test-bucket-2', key=u'infolder4/')
```

Which is fine, but I was wondering if there is a way for me to store those outputs as strings in a list. I tried to append each output to an empty list and got an empty list at the end. And string conversion didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try `list(bucket.objects.all())`?

Comment: Yep, that works. -_- Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It should be a list already, you don't need to iterate the list again. here's the doc:

```
A collection of ObjectSummary resources

all()
Creates an iterable of all ObjectSummary resources in the collection.

See also: AWS API Documentation

Request Syntax

object_summary_iterator = bucket.objects.all()
Return type
list(s3.ObjectSummary)
Returns
A list of ObjectSummary resources
```

Read more details [from the doc](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

Comment: `print(type(bucket.objects.all()))` returns `<class 'boto3.resources.collection.s3.Bucket.objectsCollection'>`